# Kohana Database instances containts wrong data

Tags: database, kohana, instance

I have a problem with Kohana database.
Sometimes I have error

```
ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ] 
Argument 1 passed to Kohana_Database_Query_Builder_Select::compile() must be an instance of Database, string given, called in /srv/sites/mysite/www/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/query.php on line 230 and defined
```

It's happens because in Database:$instances containts string "**dances**", but should contain array database configurations.

This my config:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

return array
(
'default' => array
(
    'type'       => 'MySQL',
    'connection' => array(
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'database'   => 'chat',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'root',
        'persistent' => FALSE,
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
    'profiling'    => TRUE
)
);
```

Maybe somebody had problem like this or could help me?

---

Any query to DB causes error.
Like this:

```
Jelly::factory('user', $user->id())
```

or this:

```
DB::select('value')->from('storage')->where('name', '=', 'salt')->limit(1)->execute();
```

or this:

```
ORM::factory('node')->where('type', '=', 'page-homepage')->find();
```

---

I don't know why this error happen. I checked all methods are called and I have not found any mistakes.

I solved this problem by write method `instance` in class Database

```
public static function instance($name = NULL, array $config = NULL)
{
    if ($name === NULL)
    {
        // Use the default instance name
        $name = Database::$default;
    }

    if ( ! is_array(Database::$instances))
    {
        Database::$instances = array();
    }

    if ( ! isset(Database::$instances[$name]))
    {
        if ($config === NULL)
        {
            // Load the configuration for this database
            $config = Kohana::$config->load('database')->get($name);
        }

        if ( ! isset($config['type']))
        {
            throw new Kohana_Exception('Database type not defined in :name configuration',
                array(':name' => $name));
        }

        // Set the driver class name
        $driver = 'Database_'.ucfirst($config['type']);

        // Create the database connection instance
        new $driver($name, $config);
    }

    return Database::$instances[$name];
}
```

I add condition As you can see

```
if ( ! is_array(Database::$instances))
{
    Database::$instances = array();
}
```

I don't like this, but I have no choise.

Comment: Can you maybe show a piece of code where you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess would be that you seem to be overwriting the `compile`, `quote`, `quote_column`, `quote_identifier`, `quote_table` or `execute` method from `Kohana_Database` in your code or simply calling `->execute('dances')` should trigger this error.

the `compile` method shouldn't be called directly, it's an internal function that is called from `execute()`

Any of these functions take `$db` as the first parameter. Don't pass anything, since you want to use the database set in your config file, without trying to set it manually in your query builder.

Comment: No. This methods didn't overwrited. Method `execute` called without parameters. And this error happens from time to time without regularities.